# What Exception is thrown on timeout?

Tags: java, exception, testing, timeout, htmlunit

What Exception is thrown on connection timeout in HTMLUnit ?

Comment: Perhaps you should try and see...

Answer (score 2):

HtmlUnit uses the Apache HttpClient.  The timeout mechanism throws an [InterruptedIOException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InterruptedIOException.html).

See the [HttpClient documentation](http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/api/HTTPClient/HTTPConnection.html#setTimeout%28int%29).

This exception is a subclass of IOException, which can be thrown during any HttpClient execute call (basically whenever you get a page with an HtmlUnit WebClient.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug, it really should throw a exception but dont throw if you set an timeout great than a value, you can see it in ([[Call getPage from htmlunit WebClient with JavaScript disabled and setTimeout set to 10000 waits forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915695/call-getpage-from-htmlunit-webclient-whith-javascript-disabled-and-settimeout-set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915695/call-getpage-from-htmlunit-webclient-whith-javascript-disabled-and-settimeout-set))

Thanks a lot