# Call getPage from htmlunit WebClient with JavaScript disabled and setTimeout set to 10000 waits forever

Tags: java, timeout, htmlunit

I'm having problems with Htmlunit, I disabled JavaScript and set timeout to 10000 before calling getpage, I expected an exception after timeout but htmlunit waits forever.

After some search I realized someone in 2009 had the same problem ([Connection timeout not working](https://web.archive.org/web/20110207195739/http://old.nabble.com/Connection-timeout-not-working-td26197231.html)), he was complaining about "Connection timeout not working" and about some values in timeout not working but until now in 2011 didn't get any answer.

Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690358/what-exception-is-thrown-on-timeout/4917577#4917577) was asking about what exception is thrown but I think it doesn't throw it always. I can't get an answer from [Apache HttpClient setTimeout](http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/api/HTTPClient/HTTPConnection.html#setTimeout%28int%29), either. You can see another person asking about stop in timeout in [Terminate or Stop HtmlUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4906806).

You can see how crazy it is if you try:

```
milisecReqTimeout = 10;
while(true)
{
    _webclient.setTimeout(milisecReqTimeout);
    milisecReqTimeout = milisecReqTimeout + 10;
    _htmlpage = _webclient.getPage(url);
}
```

Comment: Why you dont replace HtmlUnit for Jaxer ?

Comment: Save your cookie session data in a file and turn processing parallel loading it on many webclient instances. Maybe it can help you too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237286/how-to-save-htmlunit-cookies-to-a-file

Comment: You can use it too [How to make 2 HtmlUnit's WebClients use same cookies?]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043745/how-to-make-2-htmlunits-webclients-use-same-cookies

Comment: Use the @aboutuigrid comment url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043745/how-to-make-2-htmlunits-webclients-use-same-cookies to create an login provider an use it as an visitor.

Answer (score 3):

```
     _thewebclient.setWebConnection(new HttpWebConnection(_thewebclient) {
     @Override
     protected synchronized AbstractHttpClient getHttpClient() {
         AbstractHttpClient client = super.getHttpClient();
         if (_TimeoutCliSocket > 0) {
             //Sets the socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) in milliseconds to
             //be used when executing the method.
             //A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
             //Time that a read operation will block for, before generating 
             //an java.io.InterruptedIOException
             client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 
                                                      _TimeoutCliSocket);
         }
         if (_TimeoutCliConnection > 0) {
             //The timeout in milliseconds used when retrieving an
             // HTTP connection from the HTTP connection manager.
             // Zero means to wait indefinitely.
             client.getParams().setParameter("http.connection-manager.timeout", 
                                                     _TimeoutCliConnection);
         }
         client.getParams().setParameter("http.tcp.nodelay", true);
         return client;
     }
 });
```

Bye

Comment: wow this works!! after such a long time looking for an answer! nearly gave up. thanks!

Comment: i take it back. looks like it doesnt after all. thread is still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I found, with HttpUnit 1.6.2 setting these

```
    final HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    final GetMethod method = new GetMethod(pUrl);

    client.setConnectionTimeout((int) timeout);
    client.setTimeout((int) timeout);

    final int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
```

Seemed to do the trick.  Both are deprecated methods. :(

Comment: Thanks a lot for it, its so late here in Brazil now 00:19 but tomorrow i will try it, no problem that its deprecated i hope change htmunit layer in future.