# How to call getPage from HtmlUnit WebClient and have setTimeout not wait forever?

Tags: settimeout, htmlunit

I have the same problem as described in the question [Call getPage from htmlunit WebClient with JavaScript disabled and setTimeout set to 10000 waits forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915695/call-getpage-from-htmlunit-webclient-whith-javascript-disabled-and-settimeout-se).

There is only one relevant (complicated) possible answer there ([by theytoo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137113/444991)). So I was wondering if:

1. Does someone have a simpler answer?
2. Can someone verify the solution works?

Comment: Maybe it'd be a good idea to provide the most simple code that leads to this exception not being thrown and also the HtmlUnit version you're using.

Comment: Ya, I've got one too (a ). We are at HtmlUnit 2.9 How about:

Comment: Ya, I've got one too (a moustache). We are at HtmlUnit 2.9 How about: webClient = new WebClient(); webClient().setTimeout(180000); page=webClient.getPage("myurl"); in a big try-catch...

Answer (score 3):

Code I used:

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.setTimeout(1000);
        try {
            System.out.println("Querying");
            webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");
            System.out.println("Success");
        } catch (final FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
            System.out.println("One");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Two");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Three");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Four");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

}
```

Output (removed all CSS and JS warnings):

```
Querying
Success
Finished
```

After changing timeout from 1000 to 1 (I won't hit google in less than 1 ms):

```
Querying
Three
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to www.google.com:80 timed out
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.SocksSocketFactory.connectSocket(SocksSocketFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:776)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:152)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1439)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1358)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:307)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:373)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:358)
    at main.Test.main(Test.java:17)
Finished
```

Conclusion: I can't reproduce it and it works as expected

Comment: Ya, well, good effort I guess, but if my question was that easy, I would not have put it on StackOverflow. Based on the and also based on the doc at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/DefaultClientConnectionOperator.html

Comment: ... Based on the aformentioned other StackOverflow question and also based on the doc at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/DefaultClientConnectionOperator.html I will try 2 things (they are config parameters so that's easy): 1) reduce drastically the timeout from 3 minutes to "some"(?) seconds and 2) put the IP address flat out in the URL instead of the site domain. Thanks for your ideas; will keep you informed, A.R.

Comment: What version are you using? I am using htmlunit 2.20 and there's no `setTimeout` method in WebClient.