# HtmlUnit dependencies

Tags: htmlunit

Can anyone point me to a current example of how to use HTMLUnit to interact with a webpage (submit a form, click, etc) along with the current jars that work with the example? I donwloaded all the jars on the htmlunit page and all its dependent jars, and I keep getting NoSuchMethod errors, so I'm guessing I have mismatched jars.

Comment: Are you familiar with Maven and Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you're having issues to set up HtmlUnit this answer might help [How to setup HtmlUnit in an Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096433/eclipse-htmlunit-jars-within-a-jar-different-pc-fail/9122852#9122852)

Regarding form submission and clicking, this is the example taken from the HtmlUnit documenation itself:

```
public void submittingForm() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    // Get the first page
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://some_url");

    // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
    // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
    HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("myform");

    HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("submitbutton");
    HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("userid");

    // Change the value of the text field
    textField.setValueAttribute("root");

    // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMLUnit is integrated in Selenium WebDriver. http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

the best advice that I can give you is, since you are working with Java, make it a Maven Project and add the dependencies for selenium.webdriver. Building the project as Maven avoids having common mistakes like saving the jars in a wrong directory or forgetting 1 jar