# Java: create webclient / htmlunit exception

Tags: exception, webclient, htmlunit

I don't know how to fix this problem... 
Will you help me please?

I get this exeption: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: etc.`

My code is:

```
package mainsrc;
```

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

```
 public void search () throws Exception {
```

WebClient wb = new WebClient ();
 }

Comment: have you looked into what typically causes a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`?

Comment: Yes I've, but I still can't figure out whats wrong. Aint a professional.

Comment: You haven't setup HTMLUnit properly. Check this question [How to setup HtmlUnit in an Eclipse project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096433/how-to-setup-htmlunit-in-an-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better use selenium-firefox-driver-2.0a5.jar and imitate the Firefox browser as in the following code fragment. You may use chrome also.

Use the following imports and select a web browser
and furthermore you have to use selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar or above versions

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;//you already use this
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;

WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("Page url");
```