# HTMLUnit getPage NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsoup, htmlunit

I've been experiencing problems with the following source code:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Boris on 14-1-2.
 */
public class Parser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

        WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("http://oddsportal.com"));
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);

        int i = webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);

        while (i > 0)
        {
            i = webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);

            if (i == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            synchronized (page)
            {
                System.out.println("wait");
                page.wait(500);
            }
        }

        webClient.getAjaxController().processSynchron(page, request, false);

        System.out.println(page.asXml());

    }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/pool/ConnPoolControl
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.createHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:557)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:518)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:155)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1486)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1403)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:305)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:390)
    at DIIParser.Parser.main(Parser.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.pool.ConnPoolControl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 25 more
```

I read a lot about the topic, included browser version to WebClient, switched to the old version 4.2 of org.apache.httpcomponents, tried casting HtmlPage as stated in another topic here but nothing helps. All I want is to load a particular page and wait until the javascript is executed, after that parse it with jsoup. Thank you in advance for your help!

Regards,
Boris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you haven't explained what you have done so far to get that error I guess you haven't imported the appropriate libraries. Make sure you import **all** the libraries that come in the HTMLUnit distribution.

You can take a look at how to do this in Eclipse in the following question, maybe it can help:
[How to setup HtmlUnit in an Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096433/how-to-setup-htmlunit-in-an-eclipse-project/9122852#9122852)

By the way, there is no need to switch to any *old version*. Just import the libraries and you're done.

Comment: I am using maven so I added the dependency.

<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
  <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
  <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>

Comment: When I added htmlunit-2.13-bin.zip it worked, very strange why with maven it doesn't.. thank you!