# HtmlUnit on webserver: method <init>()V not found

Tags: webserver, htmlunit, nosuchmethoderror

I've managed to run the code in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081743/how-to-call-getpage-from-htmlunit-webclient-and-have-settimeout-not-wait-forever) properly in a test java project with no problem, but when I am following the exact same procedure to import HtmlUnit in my webserver, i keep getting the `org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext: method <init>()V not found` error.

the code im trying to run:

```
    package com.testing;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

public class testingUnit {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.setTimeout(1000);
        try {
            System.out.println("Querying");
            webClient.getPage("https://bulksms.vsms.net/register/");
            System.out.println("Success");
        } catch (final FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
            System.out.println("One");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Two");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Three");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Four");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

}
```

Console:

```
Querying
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext: method <init>()V not found
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:797)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:776)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:152)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1439)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1358)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:307)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:373)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:358)
    at com.testing.testingUnit.main(testingUnit.java:16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after posting the screenshot here. I had totally forgot to update the web app libraries. I did that and deleted all the outdated versions of jars I had (in the webcontent/lib folder), and the code above worked like a charm. Cheers!

Comment: hi Alex , what are the jar file , u deleted . I'm facing same problem